# Which Linux kernel version support uffdio_writeprotect structure and how to compile and install that linux kernel?

Tags: linux

I have try to compile a program which manage userfault-fd to collect some dirty pages on memory. In this program i have used the uffdio_writeprotect structure to survey a memory region where program try to access. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with linux kernel version 5.14.0. But when i compile a program with the command **gcc -o with_userfault -I. with_userfault.c**
i still have the same errors such as: with_userfault.c:108:34: error: storage size of ‘wp’ isn’t known
struct uffdio_writeprotect wp;
with_userfault.c:114:21: error: ‘UFFDIO_WRITEPROTECT’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘UFFDIO_REGISTER’?
if (ioctl(fd, UFFDIO_WRITEPROTECT, &wp) == -1)
I don't know how to solve this problem. Please I need your help to solve this issue because i don't know what i am suppose to do now. thanks!!!!!
this is a source code:

The header file:

```
#ifndef __RDTSC_H_DEFINED__
#define __RDTSC_H_DEFINED__


#if defined(__i386__)

static __inline__ unsigned long long rdtsc(void)
{
  unsigned long long int x;
     __asm__ volatile (".byte 0x0f, 0x31" : "=A" (x));
     return x;
}
#elif defined(__x86_64__)

static __inline__ unsigned long long rdtsc(void)
{
  unsigned hi, lo;
  __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi));
  return ( (unsigned long long)lo)|( ((unsigned long long)hi)<<32 );
}

#elif defined(__powerpc__)

static __inline__ unsigned long long rdtsc(void)
{
  unsigned long long int result=0;
  unsigned long int upper, lower,tmp;
  __asm__ volatile(
                "0:                  \n"
                "\tmftbu   %0           \n"
                "\tmftb    %1           \n"
                "\tmftbu   %2           \n"
                "\tcmpw    %2,%0        \n"
                "\tbne     0b         \n"
                : "=r"(upper),"=r"(lower),"=r"(tmp)
                );
  result = upper;
  result = result<<32;
  result = result|lower;

  return(result);
}

#else

#error "No tick counter is available!"

#endif


/*  $RCSfile:  $   $Author: kazutomo $
 *  $Revision: 1.6 $  $Date: 2005/04/13 18:49:58 $
 */

#endif
```

The source file

```
/*
 * Example program about using userfaultfd(2) for garbage collection.
 *
 * This establishes a couple pages, all of which are filled from
 * compressed files on disk when first accessed.  For simplicity 
 * these are 
 * one file per page.  Files are written at the beginning of the 
 * program.
 *
 * Later, this program demonstrates the use of write protection to 
 * get 
 * a notification on write access, analogous to using 
 * mprotect(!PROT_WRITE)
 * and doing the bookkeeping in a SIGSEGV handler.
 *
 */

#include <linux/userfaultfd.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>

#include <poll.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include "rdtsc.h"

//#define size 102400
#define FILE_BUF 25
#define PAGE_SIZE sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)
#define n_pages 102400
//102400
#define iterations 1

pthread_t tracker;
void *tracker_task();
int i;
unsigned long main_tsc_start, main_tsc_end;

// This is doing the work in the uffd handler thread
void *tracker_task(void *data)
{ 
  int fd = *(int *)(data); 

  for (;;)
  {
    struct uffd_msg msg;
    struct pollfd pollfd;
    int pollres, readret;
    unsigned long addr, page_begin, whichpage;
    unsigned long handler_tsc_start, handler_tsc_end;

    pollfd.fd = fd;
    pollfd.events = POLLIN;
    pollres = poll(&pollfd, 1, -1);

    if( pollres == -1 )
      perror("poll");

    if (pollfd.revents & POLLERR)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "POLLERR on userfaultfd\n");
      exit(1);
    }

    readret = read(fd, &msg, sizeof(msg));
    if (readret == -1)
      perror("read userfaultfd");

    if (readret != sizeof(msg))
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "short read, not expected, exiting\n");
      exit(1);
    }

    
    /*
     * Proper sequence is important here.
     *
     * For the GC we expect that write-protected pages can only
     * be pages already backed by physical pages.
     * Regular writes into unprotected pages that come before
     * reads need the page be filled.
     *
     * So we do the WP case first and get it out of the way.
     * Then both of the other cases need the page read.
     */

    if (msg.arg.pagefault.flags & UFFD_PAGEFAULT_FLAG_WP)
    {
      //  send write unlock
      struct uffdio_writeprotect wp;
      wp.range.start = msg.arg.pagefault.address;
      wp.range.len = PAGE_SIZE;  
      wp.mode = 0;
      //printf("sending !UFFDIO_WRITEPROTECT event to 
      //userfaultfd\n");

      if (ioctl(fd, UFFDIO_WRITEPROTECT, &wp) == -1)
        perror("ioctl(UFFDIO_WRITEPROTECT)");

      //continue;
       }
  }
  printf("end\n");
  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  unsigned long *region;
  int uffd, uffd_flags, expected, t_create;
  void *status;
  struct uffdio_writeprotect wp;
  struct uffdio_api uffdio_api;
  struct uffdio_register uffdio_register;
  char *clear = "3", *drop_caches_path = "/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches";
  FILE *drop_caches_file;
  
  main_tsc_start = rdtsc();

  uffd = syscall(__NR_userfaultfd, O_CLOEXEC | O_NONBLOCK);
  if (uffd == -1)
  {
    perror("syscall");
    exit(2);
  }

  uffdio_api.api = UFFD_API;
  uffdio_api.features = 1;
  if (ioctl(uffd, UFFDIO_API, &uffdio_api))
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "UFFDIO_API\n");
    return 1;
  }

  //printf("Features: 0x%llx\n", uffdio_api.features);
  if (uffdio_api.api != UFFD_API)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "UFFDIO_API error %Lu\n", uffdio_api.api);
    return 1;
  }

  /* Allocate memory that will be tracked */
  region = (unsigned long *) mmap(NULL, PAGE_SIZE * n_pages, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANON, -1, 0);
  if (!region)
  {
    perror("mmap");
    exit(2);
  }
  /* Force alignment of contiguous pages */
  if (posix_memalign((void **)region, PAGE_SIZE, PAGE_SIZE * (n_pages - 1)))
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "cannot align by PAGE_SIZE %ld\n", PAGE_SIZE);
    exit(1);
  }

  uffdio_register.range.start = (unsigned long)region;
  uffdio_register.range.len = PAGE_SIZE * n_pages;
  uffdio_register.mode = UFFDIO_REGISTER_MODE_WP;

  //main_tsc_start = rdtsc();
  if (ioctl(uffd, UFFDIO_REGISTER, &uffdio_register) == -1)
  {
    perror("ioctl(UFFDIO_REGISTER)");
    exit(1);
  }

  expected = UFFD_API_RANGE_IOCTLS;
  if ((uffdio_register.ioctls & expected) != expected)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "ioctl set is incorrect\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  if( (t_create = pthread_create(&tracker, NULL, tracker_task, 
      &uffd)) != 0 )
  {
        errno = t_create;
        perror("pthread_create");
  }

  //printf("mainline writing writable pages.\n");
  for (unsigned long i = 0; i < n_pages; i++)
  {
    unsigned long entry = (i * PAGE_SIZE / sizeof(unsigned long)) + ((rand()%10000) % 512);//(i % 512);
    region[entry] = i;
  }

  drop_caches_file = fopen(drop_caches_path, "w");
  for (i = 0; i < iterations; i++)//
  {
    /* Indicate the range of pages to be write-protected */
    //sync();
    fwrite(clear, sizeof(clear), 1, drop_caches_file);
    wp.range.start = (unsigned long long)region;
    wp.range.len = PAGE_SIZE * n_pages;
    wp.mode = UFFDIO_WRITEPROTECT_MODE_WP;

    /* Write-protect pages */
    if (ioctl(uffd, UFFDIO_WRITEPROTECT, &wp) == -1)
    {
      perror("ioctl(UFFDIO_WRITEPROTECT)");
      exit(1);
    }

    /* Now try to "touch" the pages to trigger page faults and handling by the tracker thread */
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < n_pages; i++)
    {
      unsigned long entry = (i * PAGE_SIZE / sizeof(unsigned long)) + ((rand()%10000) % 512);//(i % 512);
      region[entry] = i;
    }
  }
  fclose(drop_caches_file);

  if (ioctl(uffd, UFFDIO_UNREGISTER, &uffdio_register.range)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ioctl unregister failure\n");
    return 1;
  }

  main_tsc_end = rdtsc();

  printf("Apllication TSC : %lu\n", (unsigned long) (main_tsc_end-main_tsc_start));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think you might be missing the neccessary kernel headers. Follow https://askubuntu.com/questions/75709/how-do-i-install-kernel-header-files to install them, According to https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_userfaultfd.2.html kernel 5.14.0 should be appropriate.

Comment: Googling "UFFDIO_WRITEPROTECT" finds a manpage that says "(Since Linux 5.7)".

Comment: Please can you give me more explanation about the information that I am suppose to found there???? I am not able to compile that program in my computer!

Comment: I am using Linux Kernel version 5.11.0 with Ubuntu 18.04.06 LTS in my computer!

Comment: I have found solution in my problem. Excuse me to reply now. For those who meet the same problem they can just find kernel greater than version 5.7 and compile it. after compilation, they will just go on root folder of kernel and run the following command line: make headers_install INSTALL_HDR_PATH=/usr. I think that this command will solve their problem. You can close this post because it is ok for me.